# Why does headless IRI fullnode without PoW keep CPU at 100%?

Tags: iri-node, cpu

I am running 24/7 headless IRI fullnode on an i3 workstation with 32Gb RAM. My fullnode is almost always sinchronized with the tangle.

I run the node with the option:

`--remote-limit-api "removeNeighbors, addNeighbors, interruptAttachingToTangle, attachToTangle, getNeighbors"`

Why does IRI running keep the CPU at 100% even if nobody is launching PoW on it?

**Update**

After upgrading to IRI 1.4.1.4 the CPU is less frequently at 100%. Probably this is due to a better management of the invalid transactions.

Comment: Are you sure it's the IRI that keeps the CPU under load?

Comment: Yes, it is clear with htop and starting/stopping IRI.

Comment: my cpu is sometimes at over 200%, lol. I heard about even higher numbers (I guess, that depends on the amount of cores).

Answer (score 1):

you may consider using something like `cpulimit` to throttle it.
You can get it with your package manager.
On apt systems:
`sudo apt install cpulimit`
Run `top`, and find your Process ID for IRI.
Then you can initiate cpulimit for that process with proper privileges:
`cpulimit --pid 13131 --limit 71 --background`

This will help to throttle your cpu to 71 % ont he iri process, if IRI was running with a PID of 13131 (check top).

Comment: Thank you, `cpulimit` is very useful and effective.

Answer (score 1):

You also may want to check your incoming traffic. In my case the CPU load is directly proportional to the incoming traffic.

The incoming traffic in the image below is caused by one single neighbor suddenly sending a lot of data to the server.

[image]